# most interested in our offer

Tags: adjectives, superlatives

a. Ron was most interested in our offer.

b. Ron was the most interested in our offer.

c. Ron was interested in our offer the most.

d. Ron was interested in our offer most.

I think in (b), (c) and (d) 'most' is a marker for the superlative. Ron was interested in our offer more than in the others.

(b), (c) and (d) could also mean he was interested in our offer more than the other people were.

I find (a) ambiguous. It might have both of the meanings of (c) and it could also mean he was 'very interesed in our offer'.

Am I correct?

Many thanks

Comment: I agree with your conclusions

Comment: I would regard 'extremely interested' as the _primary_ meaning of (a).

Comment: (c) and (d) aren't idiomatic, so there's no point in wasting time analyzing them. (a) means Ron was ***very*** interested, and (b) means he was more interested than anyone else. In case (b), even if in fact Ron was only *slightly* interested, he might still be more interested than everyone else (who might all be ***totally uninterested***).

Comment: c) is okay in speaking, just not in writing.

Comment: @Lambie: To you, maybe. Certainly not to me. Sounds like something a non-native speaker might say.

Comment: In U.S. English, I'd not draw a distinction with respect to (c) between written and spoken usage. Rather, I'd draw a distinction between formal and informal discourse. Seeing (c) in a note or email would not surprise me at all. Hearing it in the State of the Union address would surprise me. That FF would tag me as a non-native speaker of British English is right on target. I do not even pretend to know that language.

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit hasty re d). It is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

In U.S. English, (a), (b), and (c) are idiomatic whereas (d) is not idiomatic. (c), however, is not in a particularly formal register and may have multiple meanings.

Although I greatly respect Colin Fine, I do not find (a) to be ambiguous. It means

> Ron was very interested in our offer.

It does not imply that Ron was more interested than others to whom such an offer was made. It does not even imply that similar offers were made to anyone other than Ron. It is not a comparative statement in any inter-personal sense. (This may not be the case in British English, but see the slight difference in the interpretations of (a) by Kate Bunting and FF, both knowledgeable speakers of British English.)

Unlike FF, whom I also greatly respect, I do not find (c) to be unidiomatic in U.S. English although it is somewhat informal in register. Moreover, it **MAY** imply more than (b). As FF says, (b) does not imply that anyone other than Ron had any interest whatsoever. In American usage, (c) likely implies that others were interested, but does not assert that as a fact.

Comment: D is wrong in any English and the others are standard is all varieties of English.

Comment: @Lambie I never opine on British or Indian English. They are different enough from U.S. English that I limit myself to what I am confident I know. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Most standard expressions are the same in British English etc. Indian English is a special case.

Comment: It is the ones that are not the same that create difficulties.